# Show that $\sin(\pi*x/2)=1-x$

Tags: calculus

So I need to show that $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})=1-x$

Do I need to use the half-angle formula?

This is my attempt:

Since $\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$

$\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos (\pi x)}{2}}$

since $\cos\pi=-1$, we have $\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-(-1)}{2}} = \pm1$

But this is obviously not the answer. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is not true. If $x=0$ you have $0=1.$

Comment: So you are to prove that the sine is a linear function?

Comment: This is not even remotely true, even in the sense of approximations ($x\approx 0$). Either you missed out something in the problem statement, or the question is flat out wrong.

Comment: Do you need to show that the sine is a linear function, or find the intersection of the two functions?